# Can i use an AFCI breaker on a 240 V AC unit that has no neutral?

Tags: electrical

Can I use an afci breaker on a 240 v with no neutral

Comment: How many amps is the 240V circuit?

Comment: Are you saying the breaker has no neutral or the panel has no neutral (like a pre 1999 sub panel 240 only)? A bit more info would be helpful like the brand and size.

Answer (score 1):

### You will need neutral on the supply side.

Any AFCI breaker requires neutral *to power itself*.  That means it will work in normal panels just fine.  The snag is that if you are trying to install an AFCI at a remote disconnect or subpanel where neutral was not brought there (because the equipment does not use it), installing AFCI there will be problematic.

Also pointless, since the main point of AFCI is to protect wires and connections from arcing problems.  Protecting appliances is not the primary goal (but it does help with high-risk appliances such as electric blankets).

### 2-pole AFCIs will work fine.

Assuming the breaker has neutral.... If it is a 2-pole 240V AFCI breaker that is 2 spaces wide and has 3 output terminals, then yes, you are under no obligation to use the neutral output terminal.

### 1-pole AFCIs, *probably* not, but check.

On a 240V-only (no neutral) circuit, you can use 2 *plain* 120V breakers **with a handle-tie** to protect the circuit, since common trip is not required on a 240V-only circuit.   Can you do that with 1-pole AFCI breakers?  Don't get your hopes up, but *maybe*.

**You must use breakers of the correct model for your panel model. Breakers are NOT interchangeable even if they seem to fit! Even if 30% of electricians and 98% of hardware store clerks will tell you they interchange! They do not. Buy the correct breakers for your panel!**

Certain manufacturers are *just starting* to make AFCI breakers that do not require the circuit's neutral wire.  They probably require the neutral pigtail to power themselves, but the circuit neutral goes on the neutral bar like plain breakers.

If you find one of these breakers, read the breaker instructions regarding use of this breaker on *Multi-Wire Branch Circuits* (MWBC) aka shared neutral circuits.  Whatever it says for that will also apply to 240V-only (no neutral) circuits like yours.

Comment: Great answer.  I did not know that AFCI breakers with no neutral were even a thing - I figured the neutral on an AFCI was more of a "through" connection rather than just powering the circuitry since even my AFCI breakers with plug-on neutrals still had both output terminals.

Comment: @ChrisO Thanks.  It actually is a thru connection, on those that require the circuit neutral.  They have an internal GFPE (weak GFCI) to detect hot-ground and neutral-ground *arc faults*, which also happen to be ground faults.  As such they must wire like a GFCI.  New models are starting to emerge whose DSP technology is good enough to do that sensing electronically.